# How to determine the creator of my calendar event in Office 365?

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook.com, power-automate

I'm using the Office 365 API to request events from my calender. To be specific I have a shared calender (the one I shared it with can edit the calendar) but when requesting data from the API I can't see the difference in organisator of the events. As I would like to send different messages based on who has added the event, I would like to know who has added it.

Is there any other property or way to identify who has added/updated the event?

Comment: Would you provide with more detail on what Office.js API methods you are using and what information you get with them, as well as what would you like to get. Are you trying to get organizer of the event and/or attendee list? Is your add-in invocation happen for reading of the event item? You don't talk about creating event, right?

Comment: Looking at the latest API, it is contained in the Office.context.mailbox.item object:

organizer :EmailAddressDetails

Gets the email address of the meeting organizer for a specified meeting. Read mode only.

Type:
•EmailAddressDetails


Example
var organizerName = Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer.displayName;
var organizerAddress = Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer.emailAddress;


HTH,
Jim

Comment: Could you clarify if you're asking about the REST API or the Office.js Add-in framework? Two very different stacks.

Comment: I'm using the REST API

Answer (score 1):

#### The Power Automate trigger named [**When an event is added, updated or deleted (V3)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#when-an-event-is-added,-updated-or-deleted-(v3)) outputs a [**GraphCalendarEventClientWithActionType**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#graphcalendareventclientwithactiontype) which contains a property called **`Organizer`**.

---

***Example of accessing the Organizer property in a Power Automate flow:***

[image]

#### Note: For some reason Power Automate was not displaying this property when my cursor was in the `Body` field (only when my cursor is in the `Subject` field).

#### You can work around this by getting the value via an Expression:

[image]